# Converting promise to await/async

Tags: javascript, node.js

Should be a fairly simple and quick question, as I am new to using Promises and await/async

This is my original function with Promises. (I want the res.send and res.redirect to happen after the user is created)

```
router.post('/add', (req, res) => {
  const user = req.body.user;
  if (user.email && user.username && user.password) {
    User.create(createUserObject(user)).then(
    res.send(user);
    res.redirect('/login'));
  }
});
```

This is my new function with await/async.

```
router.post('/add', async (req, res) => {
  const user = req.body.user;
  if (user.email && user.username && user.password) {
    await User.create(createUserObject(user));
    await res.send(user);
    await res.redirect('/login');
  }
});
```

Is it correct that I need await on every line to make the code function the same? I am concerned that I am using await where I don't need to.

Comment: you need to use await wherever you're waiting for data. Like api calls etc. So no , not everywhere

Comment: I recommend switching to TypeScript so you know for sure when a method returns a `Promise<T>` and when it doesn't. That said, using `await` with a non-Promise will work.

Comment: *"I am concerned that I am using await where I don't need to."* Then read about what `await` does: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await . `async/await` is syntactic sugar to work with promises. `await` only makes sense to use if the value you are trying to `await` is a promise.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work

```
   router.post('/add', async (req, res) => {
      const user = req.body.user;
      if (user.email && user.username && user.password) {
        await User.create(createUserObject(user));
        res.send(user);
        res.redirect('/login');
      }
    });
```

The only time you're waiting for something is when you wait for the user to be added to the db. So, wherever you wait for something you'll typically get a promise returned. That's where you can use await.

Comment: I was thinking of this, but does this ensure that res.send and res.redirect are called only after the User is created?

Comment: @AndrewZaw: If `res.send(user);` and `res.redirect('/login');` are currently inside the `.then` callback (your first example is invalid so we don't know) and it works correctly, then yes, this `await` version will be equivalent.

Comment: yes, because those are synchronus functions. Which means they run from top to bottom. They run as long as long as they got their parameters. If the parameters were asynchronus you would have to put await infront of the params.

Comment: @Kevin.a: Nitpick: There is no such thing as "asynchronous parameters". I assume you mean that if a parameter is promise then it can/has to be `await`ed.

Comment: @FelixKling thats exactly what i mean, sorry if it was unclear to you

Comment: @Kevin.a: *I* get it, but I want to avoid confusing people who just get started with async stuff in JavaScript. By introducing your own terminology it's easy to make things appear more complicated than it really is.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct that I need await on every line to make the code function the same?

No. You *can* do, but you don't *need* to.

You only need to use `await` when a function returns a `Promise<T>`. If a function returns a "normal" value (a `string`, `number`, `Object`, etc) then the extra `await` will still work but is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put await in front of every function call, only the ones that are asynchronous and return a promise.

Assuming the line `User.create(createUserObject(user))` is the only asynchronous call, that should be the only line that needs an `await`.

On the other hand, putting await in front of every function call may not harm your code other than making it look more cluttered.